# Backbone fetch calls incrementing up each time I navigate to page

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I have 2 pages for my Backbone app.  Page 1 uses the `fetch()` method on a collection to get data.

When I navigate to Page 2, and then back to Page 1, I can see the `fetch()` data getting logged twice.  The fetch calls increment upwards with each new time that I navigate away from, and then back to Page One.

Is this a zombie view?  How do I stop this from happening?

Here is my JavaScript using Backbone:

```
var MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
  defaults: {
    'id': 'null',
    'color': '',
    'date': '',
    'name': ''
  }
});

var MyCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: MyModel,

  url: 'https://api.mongolab.com/api/1/databases/testdatabase/collections/Content?apiKey=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
});

var aCollection = new MyCollection();

var MyViewOne = Backbone.View.extend({
  el: '.js-container',

  initialize: function () {

    this.collection = aCollection;

    this.listenTo(this.collection, 'sync', this.render);

    this.collection.fetch();
  },

  template: _.template( $('#One').html() ),

  render: function () {
    console.log('render One');
    console.log(this.collection);

    this.$el.html( this.template({collection: this.collection}) );

    return this;
  }
});

var MyViewTwo = Backbone.View.extend({
  el: '.js-container',

  template: _.template( $('#Two').html() ),

  render: function () {
    console.log('render Two');

    this.$el.html( this.template() );

    return this;
  }
});

var MyRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
  routes: {
    '': 'pageOne',
    'pageone': 'pageOne',
    'pagetwo': 'pageTwo'
  },

  pageOne: function () {
    var myViewOne = new MyViewOne(); 
  },

  pageTwo: function () {
    var myViewTwo = new MyViewTwo();
    myViewTwo.render();
  }
});

var myRouter = new MyRouter();
Backbone.history.start();
```

Here is my HTML:

```
<div>
  <ul class="nav">
    <li>
        <a href="#pageone">Page One</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#pagetwo">Page Two</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="js-container">
</div>

<script type="text/template" id="One">
    Color = <%- collection.models[0].attributes.color %>
</script>

<script type="text/template" id="Two">
    Click the link "Page One" and check the console to see the fetch call for the collection incrementing.
</script>
```

Comment: You're creating a new view each time you visit a page, without ever cleaning up the old views. What I'm not clear on is what you're seeing happen multiple times. Each view instance will be listening for 'sync' events on the collection and calling render in response, fetch is only ever called when the view is instantiated (in initialize) so I'm not sure what you mean when you say you see 'fetch' happening multiple times.

Comment: @kinakuta I was thinking it is occuring because I'm not cleaning up the view, and I'm not too sure how to proceed with that: cleaning up the view.  There is a `console.log(this.collection)` which is what I see getting logged multiple times each time I navigate away from PageOne' and back too 'PageOne'

Answer (score 0):

```
var MyViewTwo = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '.js-container',
    template: _.template( $('#Two').html() ),
    initialize: function() {
        this.render();
    },

    render: function () {
    console.log('render Two');

    this.$el.html( this.template() );

    return this;
    }
});

var MyRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
        '': 'pageOne',
        'pageone': 'pageOne',
        'pagetwo': 'pageTwo'
    },

    pageOne: function () {
        this.pageView(new MyViewOne()); 
    },

    pageTwo: function () {
        this.pageView(new MyViewTwo());
    }
    pageView: function (view) {
        this.view && this.view.remove();
        this.view = view;
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you, but does that prevent the views from being in memorie when a new one is created again?  That's what I'm trying to figure out how to prevent.  I think that's why the issue is happening to me, because when I first go to Page One a view is created, then when I navigate away from and back too Page One another View is created but the first was never cleaned up. That's what I'm trying to understand, sorry if I'm not explaining it well enough.

Comment: Okay, I've edited my original answer. if you call remove() on the current view when rendering a new view, it will remove it from the DOM. If you try the code I've suggested it should keep a reference of pageOne but remove it from memory when navigating to pageTwo. Hopefully this solves your issue.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, when I try to use the pageView method as you demonstrate it does not render anything after I navigate away, and then back too pageOne.  Is this because it has been removed?

Answer (score 0):

i think this issue related to a view not being disposed
you can change your router to do clean up on navigation

```
var MyRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
  currentViewOne : null,
  currentViewTwo : null,
  routes: {
    '': 'pageOne',
    'pageone': 'pageOne',
    'pagetwo': 'pageTwo'
  },

  navigate: function () {

      if (this.currentViewTwo) {
          this.currentViewTwo.unbind();
          this.currentViewTwo = null;
      }
      Backbone.Router.prototype.navigate.apply(this, arguments);
  },

  pageOne: function () {
      this.currentViewOne  = new MyViewOne(); 
  },

  pageTwo: function () {
    this.currentViewTwo = new MyViewTwo();
    this.currentViewTwo.render();
  }
});
```